# Stubhub API not accepting calls from AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

All my requests to the API work locally but as soon as I push my code live, the API no longer accepts my calls. My site is hosted on AWS. I have contacted Stubhub multiple times, but they have yet to get back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was an old question, but I just had the same issue and found this thread while trying to solve it. Eventually I found an explanation.

I think StubHub has probably gotten DDOS'ed from EC2 servers before and some of the IP addresses are blacklisted as a result. My solution: I just created an elastic IP and associated it with my EC2 instance, and now my requests are going through successfully.

Hope that helps.